# Was Roy Mustang ever punished for participating in a genocide?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-manga

In Episode 30: The Ishvalan War of Extermination (2009 series) lieutenant Riza  Hawkeye says that she and the colonel will  receive later punishment for the war crimes they committed, that justice demands it:

> Hawkeye explains that the Colonel plans to appoint greater democratic
>   power to the national assembly and seek the prosecution of war
>   criminals like himself. Ed is shocked to hear that Roy is taking such
>   a potentially self-destructive path, but Riza declares that it is
>   their duty and penance for what they have done.
>   ([Fullmetal Alchemist Wiki)](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_30:_The_Ishvalan_War_of_Extermination_(2009_series))

but in the last episode of the anime Mustang gets appointed as an officer with a high rank. Does he get a trial in the manga?

Comment: After it is mentioned (as you stated in your question), it is not brought up again. Perhaps it is intended to be brought up again at some later date after the story has finished, and the audience never hears about it

Comment: @ThePickleTickler Expand that a little bit and you've got an answer.

Comment: It could also be that the "justice" that demands the trial is their own personal sense of justice, because they weren't the only ones to commit war crimes in Ishval and so the government having to host a trial for every individual involved in the war would be quite resource depleting.

Comment: @cyberson maybe not for the common soldiers but for the high ranking officers, especially for the general staff

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this may be more a "it's the thought the counts" moment. Yes, Hawkeye mentioned a democratic trial, but after it is mentioned (as you stated in your question), it is not brought up again.

Perhaps in the universe of FMA:B a trial actually went underway, but it happened after the events that were told to the audience, and thus we did not hear about it.

In addition, you have to remember that Mustang was blinded at the end of the series during the climax fight with Father. From [the wiki](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/Roy_Mustang), it states:

> After the battle with Father is over, Roy is treated in a medical center, conversing with Dr. Knox. He informs the doctor of his disability, and states that he will have to retire. He decides to pass the title of Führer over to Grumman. Knox then informs Roy that Dr. Marcoh was looking for him and brings the doctor over to Roy. Marcoh informs Roy that he has a Philosopher's Stone which Roy could use to regain his eyesight. Roy initially refuses, but Marcoh say that he has a plan in which they and the Ishvalans (referring to the souls in the Philosopher's Stone) can work together. Marcoh says he'll hand the stone over on the condition that Roy changes the Ishval policy, allows the Ishvalans to return to their homeland, and allow him (Marcoh) to live in Ishval as a doctor. Roy agrees to Marcoh's demands.

Either Mustang can live with his new disability (blindness), or he can heal and atone for his war crimes by rebuilding the Ishval community he previously uprooted and destroyed. I think that either of these punishments are adequate enough for Mustang's war crimes, and perhaps the writers of the anime/manga felt that these would be enough to avoid an actual trial.